# Plot line chart by grouping columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, linechart, cumulative-line-chart

I have a csv file with data that I grouped the information on months and then used cumsum to calculate the running total for the month into a dataframe.

Using this code:

```
df = df.sort_index(sort_remaining=True).sort_values('months')
df['value'] = df.groupby('months')['value'].cumsum()
```

OUTPUT example in EXCEL, but my DF will look the same with 1000's of rows:

[image: output example]

I would now like to plot a chart that groups the month and plot each value so basically I will have 12 plotted lines showing how the value moved either higher or lower over time.

The output plot will look like the following chart showing cumsum of each month:
[image: Chart showing cumsum of each month]

#

Thanks to @jezrael it is now working. Below is the plot
[image: Working Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) with `rename` for months names instead numeric and for new index values use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
d = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May',
     6 : 'Jun',7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'}

g = df.groupby('months').cumcount()
pd.pivot(index=g, columns=df['months'], values=df['value']).rename(columns=d).plot()
```

**Detail**:

```
print(pd.pivot(index=g, columns=df['months'], values=df['value']).rename(columns=d))
months    Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr
0        50.0   2.0  10.0   5.0
1        80.0   3.0  16.0  20.0
2       120.0   8.0  31.0  40.0
3       140.0  11.0  34.0  50.0
4         NaN  15.0  43.0  75.0
```

EDIT:

For define only some months for plot use `subset`:

```
months = ['Mar','Apr']
g = df.groupby('months').cumcount()
pd.pivot(index=g, columns=df['months'], values=df['value']).rename(columns=d)[months].plot()
```

Or filter months in input `DataFrame` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df[df['months'].isin([3,4])]
g = df.groupby('months').cumcount()
pd.pivot(index=g, columns=df['months'], values=df['value']).rename(columns=d)[months].plot()
```

Comment: I get index duplication error when I use the full dataset. I have uploaded the file. Any possibility you could have a look?

Comment: @davidp13 - First question is need plot index values for `axis y`?

Comment: @davidp13 - Or important data are only in columns `months` and `value` ?

Comment: I guess index values are not important, so answer was modified.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for solving my issue. I will post the graph to see.

Comment: another question pls. How would I structure the code to either choose a specific month or months and not report on all 12?